# EVE python circular dependencies

Tags: python, dependencies, eve

I prefer to store my models in separate files. In general I prefer a certain seperation of files. 
My first impression of EVE was very positive but now it is very difficult for me to create a manageable application structure for a bigger project:
my "auth" classes require an import of "app"
the models require their specific "auth" class
and in "settings.py" you need models to create apps -> dependency hell
Can anyone send me some advice or a link to a good boilerplate?

```
EVE App/
├── models/
│   ├── user.py
│   ├── ...
│   
│  
├── run.py
├── settings.py
├── auth.py
│   
└── ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you may try something like that, it might work:

app/__init__.py

```py
from eve import Eve
from flask import current_app, request

# database
from .database import db

# blueprints
from users import blueprint1
from todo import blueprint2

create_app()
    def set_username_as_none(username):
        resource = request.endpoint.split('|')[0]
        return  current_app.data.driver.db[resource].update(
            {"user" : username},
            {"$set": {"user": None}},
            multi=True
        )

    app = Eve()

    # SQL Possible Solution 1
    # register sqlalchemy to this app
    with app.app_context():
        db.init_app(app)
        Migrate(app, db)
        if not database_exists(db.engine.url):
            create_database(db.engine.url)
            print('Database créée : ' + str(database_exists(db.engine.url)))

    # SQL Possible Solution 2
    db.init_app(current_app)
        Migrate(current_app, db)
        if not database_exists(db.engine.url):
            create_database(db.engine.url)
            print('Database créée : ' + str(database_exists(db.engine.url)))

    # register the blueprint to the main Eve application
    app.register_blueprint(blueprint1)
    app.register_blueprint(blueprint2)
    # bind the callback function so it is invoked at each user deletion
    app.users_deleted += set_username_as_none

    return app
```

run.py

```py
instance = create_app()
instance.run()
```

app/Models/...In each model

```py
from ..database import db

class Plop(db.model):
```

app/database.py

```py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy() # you can override model there ex : model=MyModel
```